# post request to server sending empty { }

Tags: c#, node.js

I'm trying to send a post request from c# to my node js server. The request successfully reaches node js but logs an empty dictionary when I print out the body. Where did I go wrong? What is the proper way to send a post request with C sharp? Thanks in advance.

**C#**

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static async Task<string> GetCred()
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
            { "test1", "1" },
            { "test2", "2" }
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, Formatting.Indented);

            var stringContent = new StringContent(json);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://publicIp:port/api/server", stringContent);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseString;
        }
```

**Node js**

```
const server = async (req, res) => {
  //prints empty {}
  console.log(req.body);
}
```

Comment: What does the `values` object look like before you post it? I wonder if formatting it is appropriate? I’d expect the server to be able to handle JSON with line breaks and tabs, but why ask it to?

Comment: @padeso formatting the value shouldn't be a reason why it's sending an empty body don't you think?

Comment: Have you verified that the client is sending an empty body?